# Bot Framework Composer - Adaptive Card - Button to start another dialog

Tags: json, bots, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I have 2 buttons on the adaptive card."submit" button brings me the information I entered on the form.but the "cancel" button does the same.I want the "Cancel" button to redirect to another dialog when pressed. Any idea?

```
{
        "type": "ActionSet",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit",
                "style": "positive"
            },
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Cancel",
                "associatedInputs": "none",
                "id": "cancel",
                "style": "destructive"
                
            }
            ]
    }
```

Comment: hellloooo? any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the steps

1. Assign value in submit and cancel button
2. based on the value bot received , check the condition invoke the dialog

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this.

Comment: If its fine , mark as answered so it will help for others - Thank you

Comment: done. I have 1 more question. is there any chance to disable button after clicked?

Comment: No - Its not possible